# Displaying object with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I was following a tutorial and I got a question about displaying a object in my view called listing.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <h1>{{{$post->title}}} By {{{$post->user->email }}}</h1>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

However that code doesn't works, because I get a error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object.
```

The reason why I get that error, is because the variable $post is an array.

So this code does work:

```
<h1>{{{$post->title}}} By {{{$post->user['email'] }}}</h1>
```

But I don't want to use the code notation above me. I would like to use this:

```
<h1>{{{$post->title}}} By {{{$post->user->email }}}</h1>
```

Here is the code of my  controller called PostController.php:

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController {
    public function listing(){  

        $posts = Post::all();

        return View::make('post/listing', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my model called Post.php:

```
<?php 

class Post extends \Eloquent {

/*this holds all the fields that you can actually sit through
mass assignment */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];

//we set a field 'user_id' that we don't want to be set through mass assignment.
//  protected $guarded = ['user_id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Also here is the code of my model called User.php (because it has a relation with Post.php):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Could somebody please help me with my question?

Comment: It should be working as an object.

Comment: Yes I know but it doesn't for some reason. I am really telling the truth. And if you want I can record myself showing this code and the output on my browser if you want.

Comment: I would guess one of the `posts` doesn't have related `user`

Comment: Jarek you were right xD. One of my posts in the database didn't had a user. There was a post that had a user_id of 0 as a foreignkey in the posts table. But in my users table there wasn't a user with a user_id of 0. So that explains it. Anyways thanks for your replies guys!

Answer (score 1):

What I always do is use the ternary operator:

```
{{{ $post->title ?: 'No Title' }}}
```

That's equivalent to:

```
isset($post->title) ? $post->title : 'No Title';
```

That way you add a layer of security in case you missed something.

Comment: `laravel Blade` provides `{{{ $post->title or 'No Title' }}}`.